# How to redirect the k8s dashboard through NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have managed to launch the dashboard on localhost e.g.: `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` as documented on the official page [Web UI (Dashboard)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) but when I access the url I get the through the node-name I get the following error:

`Insecure access detected. Sign in will not be available. Access Dashboard securely over HTTPS or using localhost.`

According to the documentation [Login not available](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md#login-not-available) the user should either connect through localhost (not possible in my case because of headless node) or connect as https:/...

I am trying to redirect the default dashboard url to https:node.test but I can not get it working.

My current configuration:

```
server {
        listen                  443    ssl     http2;
        server_name             node.test;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/key.crt;

        ssl_ciphers                     HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
        ssl_protocols                   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        # 10MB shared ssl session with timeout 10 min
        ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout             10m;

        rewrite ^/$ http:/localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ break;
}
```

I get a 404 response sample:

```
$ curl https://node.test
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample of how I am launching the kubectl proxy:

```
$ kubectl proxy --port=8001 --address='node' --accept-hosts="^*$"
Starting to serve on IP:8001
```

How can I get the correct redirect?

[image: Dashboard UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that helps someone else in future the solution is the following:

```
server {
        listen                  443    ssl     http2;
        server_name             node.test;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/key.crt;

        ssl_ciphers                     HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
        ssl_protocols                   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        # 10MB shared ssl session with timeout 10 min
        ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout             10m;

        location / {
                proxy_pass              http://node:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/;
        }
}
```

Assuming that you have the kubectl proxy running in the background and listening:

```
$ kubectl proxy --address node --accept-hosts '.*'
Starting to serve on IP:8001
```

**Update:** In case that someone else would like to add a loadbalancer for the UI it can be done like this:

```sh
upstream kubernetes-ui-dev {
        least_conn;
        server  hostname_here:8001;
        # another server
        # another server
}

server {
        listen                          4443    ssl     http2;
        server_name                     node.test;

        ssl_certificate                 /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key             /etc/nginx/certs/key.crt;

        ssl_ciphers                     HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
        ssl_protocols                   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        # 10MB shared ssl session with timeout 10 min
        ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout             10m;

        location / {
                proxy_pass              http://kubernetes-ui-dev/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/;
        }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else also.